# In R, looking for better way to get the max value out of subgroups (groups within groups)

Tags: r, greatest-n-per-group, tidyr

For a given DF containing groups X, Y, Z, I'd like to keep the rows containing the maximum value within each of a number of columns (A_Column, C_Column, N_Column) if there is a corresponding PI value at that row. For example, for group X, maximum values should be kept for PI values C and A from the respective columns. Below is my attempt - **is there a shorter / more elegant way to achieve the same result?**

My starting DF:

```
> DF
  Group           H PI PC A_Column C_Column N_Column
1     X       AA001  C  C        2    -0.10       22
2     X         A16  A  C        3    -0.12       13
3     X    A2015_01  C  C        5    -0.80       51
4     X         AA1  C  A        2    -0.30       32
5     Y   AAA-16-04  A  A        5    -0.20       15
6     Y    A01_2009  O  A        8    -0.40       28
7     Z        AA02  A  A       17    -0.30       12
8     Z AAD003-2014  A  N        3    -0.13       43
9     Z         AD4  N  N        5    -0.60       45
```

The output I end up with:

```
> DF_max
  Group         H PI PC A_Column C_Column N_Column
1     X     AA001  C  C        2    -0.10       22
2     X       A16  A  C        3    -0.12       13
5     Y AAA-16-04  A  A        5    -0.20       15
7     Z      AA02  A  A       17    -0.30       12
9     Z       AD4  N  N        5    -0.60       45
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# toy example to get the maximum values out of every group

Group <- c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z")
H <-c("AA001","A16","A2015_01","AA1","AAA-16-04","A01_2009","AA02","AAD003-2014","AD4")
PI <- c("C","A","C","C","A","O","A","A","N")
PC <- c("C","C","C","A","A","A","A","N","N")
A_Column <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
C_Column <- -c(.1,.12,.8,.3,.2,.4,.3,.13,.6)
N_Column <- c(22,13,51,32,15,28,12,43,45)

DF <- data.frame(Group, H, PI, PC, A_Column, C_Column, N_Column)
DF

# tidy data column Values-Labels before using dplyr
gather_DF <- gather(DF, key = Col_labels, value = Obs, -Group, -H, -PI, -PC)
gather_DF

# look for value label matches within each group
gather_DF$Col_labels_match <- gather_DF$Col_labels 
map = setNames(c("A", "C", "N"), c("A_Column", "C_Column", "N_Column"))
gather_DF$Col_labels_match <- map[unlist(gather_DF$Col_labels_match)]

# get max values per group, where PI equals Col_labels
max_DF <- gather_DF %>% filter(Col_labels_match==PI) %>% group_by(Group, PI) %>% top_n(1, Obs)
max_ID <- unique(max_DF$H)
DF_max <- DF[which(DF$H %in% max_ID),] # pull max values out of DF to get original formatting
DF_max
```

**UPDATE**:
The code below uses @Arun's data.table method - however an error comes up if PI is not placed in quotes (see below; I corrected using "PI"  instead of PI) and the output does not have the right max for group gY (G=6 is coming up instead of G=17).

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("gX", "gX", "gY", "gY", "gY", "gZ", 
                               "gW", "gW", "gV", "gV", "gV", "gT", "gR", "gR", "gR", "gR", "gR", 
                               "gS", "gQ", "gL"), PI = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                   1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("C", 
                                                                                                                                   "G", "O"), class = "factor"), H = 1:20, PC = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("C", "G", "I", "O"), class = "factor"), 
                     C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2), I = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), G = c(16, 
                                                                                                                   10, 6, 17, 12, 14, 13, 11, NA, NA, NA, 9, 5, 2, 15, 3, 1, 
                                                                                                                   7, 8, 4), N = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                   NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                   NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                   NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), O = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                        NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 1, NA, 8, 4, 5, 7, 6, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Group", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "PI", "H", "PC", "C", "I", "G", "N", "O"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -20L), class = "data.frame")
df

dt <- data.table(Group=df$Group, PI=df$PI, H=df$H, PC=df$PC, 
                 C = df$C, 
                 I = df$I, 
                 G = df$G, 
                 N = df$N, 
                 O = df$O)


> Maxdt <- dt[PI %in% c("C", "I", "G", "N", "O"),
> +             .SD[which.max(get(PI))],
> +             by=.(Group, PI)]  
Error in get(PI) : invalid first argument

Maxdt <- dt[PI %in% c("C", "I", "G", "N", "O"),
                         .SD[which.max(get("PI"))],
                         by=.(Group, PI)] 



    > Maxdt
    Group PI  H PC  C  I  G  N  O
 1:    gX  G  1  G NA NA 16 NA NA
 2:    gY  G  3  G NA NA  6 NA NA
 3:    gZ  G  6  G NA NA 14 NA NA
 4:    gW  C  7  C  3 NA 13 NA NA
 5:    gV  O  9  O NA NA NA NA  3
 6:    gT  G 12  I NA NA  9 NA NA
 7:    gR  O 13  O NA NA  5 NA  8
 8:    gS  G 18  G NA NA  7 NA NA
 9:    gQ  G 19  G NA NA  8 NA NA
10:    gL  C 20  C  2  1  4 NA NA
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want as output. You write _for group X, maximum values should be kept for PI values C and A from the respective columns_, yet in your example output you throw away the row containing the `A_Column` max (5) and the `N_Column` max (51)?

Comment: OK, i get it: when PI is C you want rows with max C_Column values and when PI is A you want rows with max A_Column values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way using *data.table*:

```
dt <- data.table(Group, H, PI, PC, A=A_Column, C=C_Column, N=N_Column)
dt[PI %in% c("A", "C", "N"),
    .SD[which.max(get(PI))],
    by=.(Group, PI)]        

#    Group PI         H PC  A     C  N
# 1:     X  C     AA001  C  2 -0.10 22
# 2:     X  A       A16  C  3 -0.12 13
# 3:     Y  A AAA-16-04  A  5 -0.20 15
# 4:     Z  A      AA02  A 17 -0.30 12
# 5:     Z  N       AD4  N  5 -0.60 45
```

It should be pretty straightforward to follow what's going on. On those any of rows where `PI` matches `A,C,N`, we group by `Group, PI`.. `.SD` contains the **S**ubset of **D**ata for each group..

`get(PI)` returns the values corresponding to the character value stored in `PI` and the row corresponding to the max value of that column pointed to by `PI` is returned for each `Group, PI`.

For e.g., for the first combination, `Group=X, PI=C`. `get(PI)` == `get("C")` which returns `c(-0.1, -0.8, -0.3)` for that group on which `which.max` returns the index 1.

Comment: That is short and elegant! Thanks for showing this solution Arun.

Comment: @Arun: going back to my original dataset (much larger and not shown here) I get "Error in get(PI) : invalid first argument". Would NAs have anything to do with it?

Comment: Guessing at the problem will only waste both of our time. If you'd edit your post to include your actual data (or part of it) and your code along with the complete error, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: @Arun: in fact, after more testing, this solution appears to grab the first row in the group, and not the max in that group, though I'm not sure why....

Comment: @val, change `val` to `character` type with `dt[, PI := as.character(PI)]` and try again.. `get()` expects a char, not factor type.

Comment: @Arun: ahhh...very cool and powerful. must learn to use data.table. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(Group, PI) %>% 
  mutate(sel = (A_Column == max(A_Column)) + (C_Column == max(C_Column)) + (N_Column == max(N_Column))) %>% 
  filter(sel == max(sel)) %>% 
  select(-sel)
```

The result of the above code is:

```
# Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
# Groups: Group, PI [6]
#
#    Group           H     PI     PC A_Column C_Column N_Column
#   <fctr>      <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1      X         A16      A      C        3    -0.12       13
# 2      X    A2015_01      C      C        5    -0.80       51
# 3      Y   AAA-16-04      A      A        5    -0.20       15
# 4      Y    A01_2009      O      A        8    -0.40       28
# 5      Z AAD003-2014      A      N        3    -0.13       43
# 6      Z         AD4      N      N        5    -0.60       45
```

Comment: No, because you appear to be adding columns to select the rows. As per my post, I am looking for the max in a column given conditions in other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is shorter or more elegant, but a `data.table` way of doing this would be:

```
# Convert to data.table, rename columns and convert PI from factor to character
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
setnames(DF, c("A_Column", "C_Column", "N_Column"), c("A", "C", "N"))
DF[, PI := as.character(PI)]

# Melt A, C and N columns to allow filtering (variable == PI) when finding
# max value by group and PI
dt_melt <- melt(DF, id.vars = c("Group", "H", "PI", "PC"))
dt_max <- dt_melt[variable == PI, .(value = max(value)),
  by = .(Group, PI, variable)]

# Use Group, PI and max values as index to pull original rows from melt, and
# unique to get rid of ties
dt_idx <- unique(dt_melt[dt_max[, .(Group, PI, variable, value)],
  on = c("Group", "PI", "variable", "value")])

# Use Group, H, PI, and PC to pull original rows from DF
out <- DF[dt_idx[, .(Group, H, PI, PC)], on = c("Group", "H", "PI", "PC")]
setnames(out, c("A", "C", "N"), c("A_Column", "C_Column", "N_Column"))

# > out
#    Group         H PI PC A_Column C_Column N_Column
# 1:     X       A16  A  C        3    -0.12       13
# 2:     Y AAA-16-04  A  A        5    -0.20       15
# 3:     Z      AA02  A  A       17    -0.30       12
# 4:     X     AA001  C  C        2    -0.10       22
# 5:     Z       AD4  N  N        5    -0.60       45
```